# When I bind data in my php file to my database. I check by database and the values are all NULL? What is wrong?

Tags: php, mysql

When I bind data in my php file to my database.  I check by database and the values are all NULL?  What is wrong?

Also:  How can I pass a hashed password to be stored in my database?  I know how to password_hash and password_verify.  I can't figure out how to store a hashed password.

```
/*the variables are declared in a html form in another file.  The action attribute
```

calls this php file with this code here.  I use POST to get the user input for 
   each of the variables first, last, password, and initials*/

```
//create database connection
$dbc = mysqli_connect ('domain', 'root', 'password', 'database')
    or die ('Error connecting');

//my condition to check for value when user enters data from html form. I use POST and isset.

if (isset($_POST['first']) && isset($_POST['last']) && isset($_POST['password']) &&
 isset ($_POST['initials'])) { 

            //This is where I bind the data to prevent sql injection attacks.

    $thisdb= mysqli_prepare($dbc, "INSERT INTO database VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssd', $first, $last, $password, $initials);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($thisdb);

  mysqli_stmt_close($thisdb);
}
else 
{ echo('user missing data'); exit();}

    // close database
mysqli_close ($dbc);
```

Comment: Where are you setting the variables `$first`, `$last`, etc.?

Comment: @Barmar Registered globals maybe? (shudder)

Comment: Undeclared variables, from what I can see (so far).

Comment: `$_POST['first']` is not equal to `$first`...yet

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding - how do I know?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850896/binding-how-do-i-know)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using code of a not-any-longer-supported PHP feature (register globals) and the lack of understanding error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssd', $_POST['first'], $_POST['last'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['initials']);
```

You were binding to variables that you never assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the undefined variables that are already mentioned, you might run into problems as you are declaring your `initials` as a `double`:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssd', $first, $last, $password, $initials);
                                  ^ are you sure initials is supposed to be a double?
```

You probably want:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $_POST['first'], $_POST['last'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['initials']);
```

You should add error handling to your database to see where what problem occurs exactly.

**Note:** Storing passwords in plain text is a very bad idea, you need to salt and hash them.

Comment: Thank you.  How do send a hashed password into my mysqli_stmt_bind_param?  I know how to salt hash the password.  I can't figure how to send it into the database without it giving an error.

Comment: @user3143183 It's just a string so it should not make a difference whether you use the salted-and-hashed version or the plain-text one. As long as the database can store the number of characters the hash is.

Comment: I want to make my password secured for the user then later check it when the user logins.  So you are saying I do not need to hash the password?  I just bind it?